# How to exclude specific columns when generating entities from existing DB?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm relatively new at Hibernate and have therefore the following question:

Is there any way to exclude a specific column/s when I generate an entity from an existing DB ? For this purpose I'm using Hibernate Tools with Eclipse Luna.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the column from the generated files if you like.

Answer (score -1):

I'm also new at Hibernate, and need to generate lots of entities from a DB. After struggling myself all day long on how to do that, I finally got a decent answer: use Hibernate Tools either as a Maven plugin or with ant.

I found this interesting discussion on how to initially configure Hibernate tools as a Maven plugin: https://developer.jboss.org/message/801478#801478

Then for your specific question (which is also mine) on **How to exclude unwanted columns for the entity generation** here is the answer:

You need to write a `hibernate-reverse-engineering.xml` file something like this:

```
<table name="myTable">
    <!--...magic tricks and configurations...-->
    <column name="myColumnName" exclude="true"/>
</table>
```

But that fits just for myTable columns, not for all the columns in your DB/schema (which is what I needed =[ ). I don't see any global column-filter tag or whatsoever to tell Hibernate to ignore that column for all the tables you are mapping to JPA entities.

Here is the documentation on the `hibernate-reverse-engineering.xml` with examples and all the magic tricks you can do:
 http://docs.jboss.org/tools/latest/en/hibernatetools/html/reverseengineering.html